# I have problem with partial view in mvc core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core

I get an error in

```
foreach (var item in *Model*)
```

Model is Null - using ASP.NET Core 3.1

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> AspNetCore.Views_Products_MyIndex.ExecuteAsync() in MyIndex.cshtml
>
> @foreach (var item in Model)
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialCoreAsync(string partialViewName, object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData, TextWriter writer)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.HtmlHelper.PartialAsync(string partialViewName, object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
> AspNetCore.Views_Shared__Layout_Pigall.b__20_1() in _Layout_Pigall.cshtml
>
> @await Html.PartialAsync("/Views/Products/MyIndex.cshtml")
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext .SetOutputContentAsync()
> AspNetCore.Views_Shared__Layout_Pigall.ExecuteAsync()

Partial view

```
@model IEnumerable<DataAccessLayer.ViewModels.ProductViewModel>
<section class="container-fluid p-0 slider-section">
    <div class="row slider">
        <div class="col-12 p-0  slide-right-banner">
            <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-slider">
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                    <a class="item" href="">

                        <img src="images/@item.ImageName" alt="" class="d-none d-md-block">
                        <img src="images/@item.ImageName" alt=""
                        class="d-xl-none d-lg-none -md-none">
                    </a>

                    <a class="item" href="">
                        <img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="" class="d-none d-md-block">
                        <img src="images/slider-mob2.jpg" alt=""
                        class="d-xl-none d-lg-none d-md-none">
                    </a>
                    }

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Service

```
async Task<IEnumerable<ProductViewModel>> IProductRepositories.GetDataForProductViewModels()
{
    return await db.Products
                   .Select(x => new ProductViewModel()
                                {
                                    ID = x.ID,
                                    Title = x.Title,
                                    ShortDescription = x.ShortDescription,
                                    ImageName = x.ImageName,
                                    Count = x.Count,
                                    Fabric = x.Fabric,
                                    Price = x.Price,
                                    ShowInSlider = x.ShowInSlider,
                                    PageCount = 0
                                })
                   .ToListAsync();
}
```

Layout

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("/Views/Products/MyIndex.cshtml")
```

Comment: Is it me or your stack reports the error in _Layout_Pigall.cshtml but you suspect the error to be in MyIndex.cshtml ?  Maybe you could check if your model is null in your view before showing something as well as passing the proper model to the call Html.PartialAsync.  There are many ways to check for nulls and report the problem as an alert, an assert or any other ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line of code, you can see through the code, it will not enter the breakpoint in the `Products/MyIndex` method. So it will not read the data in your `IProductRepositories.GetDataForProductViewModels`.

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("/Views/Products/MyIndex.cshtml")
```

`@await Html.PartialAsync` is generally no problem for loading static resources.If you need to load data, you can add the following code to the page you need to open.

**Sample Code**

*Home/Index*

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<ProductViewModel> list = new List<ProductViewModel>();
        ProductViewModel p = new ProductViewModel();
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
            p.ID = i;
            p.Title = "Title" + i;
            p.ImageName = "ImageName" + i;
            list.Add(p);
        }

        ViewBag.aa = list;

        return View();
    }
```

*_Layout*

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("/Views/Products/MyIndex.cshtml", (List<ProductViewModel>)ViewBag.aa)
```

#### Suggestion

It is not recommended to use `Html.PartialAsync` on Layout pages.